# How to make searchView cursor transparent?

Tags: android, android-edittext, searchview, android-cursor

I have the following `searchView` component:

[image]

The current style is:

```
<style name="CustomToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
        <item name="android:background">#20202A</item>
</style>
```

and the current XML for the toolbar is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:theme="@style/CustomToolbarStyle"
app:titleTextColor="#FFF"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
app:collapseIcon="@drawable/returnwhite"
app:popupTheme="@style/CustomPopupStyle"
app:navigationIcon="@drawable/returnwhite"
>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

When I long click on the `searchView`, the cursor becomes as following:

[image]

I want to make it transparent, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I had finally found out the solution to do so.

I had to remove this portion `<item name="android:background">#20202A</item>`

and put `android:background="@color/topBar"` in the XML of the the toolbar

Answer (score 1):

you most set a transparent color to background in xml like below:

android:background="#00000000"

it also used to remove below line of edittext and spinner